# Validate access_token from graph.microsoft.com

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to validate an `access_token` which I get via `https://login.microsoftonline.com?.....`

Via [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) I get following information for the token. There are much more fields which are trimmed for readability.

[JWT Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eMRY.png)

```json
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "nonce": "AQABAAAAAAABlDrqfEFlSaui6xnRjX5El98dcaIDjRFfcLuFQZHkvlov2vdQMGa2qBl89-QA9pk7rk_aCmNK7VsSkAXd7HYiDoTNICVJx4rIk7iAA",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "HHdKU-0Dqh6ZFPd2VWaOtg",
  "kid": "HHDKU-0DqAqMZh6Pd2VWaOtg"
}
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/de34d790-e752-305f-93f8-e3d31df3279c2/"
}
```

I found `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` where someone passed his Bearer Token and get a success result, however during my tests I get always this error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184105",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "bd08cbc6-b870-420a-bd9e-d70a92a9f27d",
            "date": "2017-09-20T11:59:05"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide example of Authorization header?

Comment: You need to include more of your token like the SCP etc... The token header is not useful information to help resolve the issue. Can you also share your REST request in full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to tell from the truncated data here but you don't seem to have any scopes requested. Without a scope such as `user.read`, you do not have permission to call `/me`.

You're token's payload should look something along the lines of:

```json
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/b9913ffa-837d-40b3-98c3-9aca40b827a1/",
  "iat": 1505934558,
  "nbf": 1505934558,
  "exp": 1505938458,
  "aio": "...",
  "app_displayname": "...",
  "appid": "...",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "...",
  "oid": "...",
  "roles": [
    "User.Read",
    "Mail.Read"
  ],
  "sub": "...",
  "tid": "...",
  "uti": "...",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: You're right i provided not the whole token... Works fine now!
Thank you